# Rails 3 seo friendly urls without controller name

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, url-routing, seo

I have an existing website which I am attempting to port over to rails (3.2.7) and need to maintain the current urls.

Current website has urls like this:

`http://example.com/Joe`

`http://example.com/Bob`

Using rails the closest I have come is using the `friendly_id` gem and get this:

`http://example.com/users/Joe`

`http://example.com/users/Bob`

Every example I find seems to include the controller name in the url. How can I generate urls like the existing website?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have `:resources :users` somewhere in your routes.rb you can put the next route definition in file:

```
match '/:name' => "users#show"
```

This way the url /Joe will direct to UsersController show action, populating params[:name] with the string 'Joe'.

Answer (score 1):

You can find all the configuration steps needed [here](http://jasoncodes.com/posts/rails-3-nested-resource-slugs), 'Removing the controller names from URLs'

Comment: Ok, but where do I find the file like this `spec/routing/accounts_routing_spec.rb`?

Comment: The spec file is used by RSpec, if you're doing test driven development. If you're not implementing tests, just skip that passage and go to 'Updating the routes'